# Salt and MD5 in c#

Tags: c#, php, winforms, encryption

So I have a website for my game

This is an exert of the php that I am using.

```
$Login = strtolower(trim($Login));
$Pass = strtolower(trim($Pass));
$Repass = strtolower(trim($Repass));

$Salt = $Login.$Pass;
$Salt = md5($Salt);
$Salt = "0x".$Salt;
```

But now I am faced with an issue that I cant seem to work out. I need to be able to do this encryption through C# WinForms for a client side Launcher(Register, Play Game etc etc)

For the life of me I cant figure out how to make the same binary as it makes in php.

I have tried loads but just cant crack it.

Many thanks if you can help

Comment: That does not appear to be a correct use of "salt" or "encryption".

Comment: [I Googled and in three seconds I found an answer](http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1203/MD5-in-C%23---works-like-php-md5()-example).

Comment: md5() doesn't return a binary unless you tell it to. it returns a stringified version in hex representation of the md5 hash

Comment: Why isn't the password already hashed the correct way? MD5 is not good enough to protect passwords, you might as well, be storing it in plain text.  Please post your C# code if you want assistance with it, otherwise, this isn't a good question.

Comment: Based on the question, the password might very well be plaintext. OP: A salt is any random value that can be sent in plaintext and used during computation, the more random the better. Generating the same value from the same name/pass combo every time defeats the purpose.

Comment: Throw the code out on both sides, and replace it by something secure.

Comment: The program that uses this encryption cant be changed since I dont have the source code for it.

Sorry for my vague question I am not the best at explaining things.
I am trying to make this encryption work in C#(the same way it would PHP) I have tried but I always turn up with results like 0xeo8e0//28yheh312jfd07f2

Although when used in PHP I never have characters like //

Not sure if I am doing it right and just thinking its wrong or I am just doing it wrong

Comment: @MatthewCrayston did my answer help you? If so, could you please accept it? Comment on it or otherwise indicate that it isn't usefull to you if not.

Answer (score 2):

Though your example code confuses the actual question, I think I have a solution for your actual problem.

I've had the same problem with that `md5()` medthod, converting some PHP code into C# a while back. Here's what I came up with:

```
private static string CalculateChecksum(string inputString)
{
    var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    var hashbytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
    var hashstring = "";
    foreach(var hashbyte in hashbytes)
        hashstring += hashbyte.ToString("x2");

    return hashstring;
}
```

There may be a neater solution, but that there is working for me and at the time I was in a hurry.

Anyway, it gives you strings like `A48EDF06 ...` as you would expect from `php`'s `md5()`